# Policyd-rate-limit for Postfix correctly configured but still wont work

Tags: debian, postfix, policyd

I have tested policyd-rate-limit on my developer server and there is everything work correctly.
But my production server wont work with policyd-rate-limit.
My configuration:

Postfix
( dev ) version: 3.4.13
( prod ) version: 3.1.15

main.cf:

```
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service { unix:ratelimit/policy, default_action=DUNNO } 
....
```

In logs /var/log/syslog I dont see any entry like this example: 001/001 hit since 60s or insert id example-user@mail-domain.com
So daemon policyd-rate-limit cant defer the message.
Of course I dont see any errors in logs. Database has been tested mysqlite and mysql and yaml configure package for Python3. Unfortunately stil no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

OK problem has been solved.
Policyd-rate-limit installed from default debian repository ( Debian 9.13 ) cant correctly to work with Postfix 3.1.15.
So I have uninstalled package policyd-rate-limit along with configuration files.
After I installed manually policyd-rate-limit using pip3. Of course it needs to be copied manually config file and init scripts/services files to correct location. After standard configuration it works. I noticed also that option "limits_by_id" dont work in this case :(